# getElementById.value and getElementById.value?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a problem regarding this two values from my textboxes (text, text2), seems like text2 only show its value, is there any way I can get rid of these things. Any help would be so much appreciated.

```
parameters = ('text=' + document.getElementById('text').value) && ('text2=' + document.getElementById('text2').value;

xmlhttp.open('POST', 'try.php', true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xmlhttp.send(parameters);
```

Comment: the code above will set `parameters` to `text2=` `text2 value` if `text= ` `text value` is not null (which is always true), so if you want to concatenate `text=`, `text value`, `&`, `text2=`, and `text2 value` (It's very hard for me to explain it :D), you should use `+` operator instead of `&&`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
parameters = ('text=' + document.getElementById('text').value) && ('text2=' + document.getElementById('text2').value;
```

This line is wrong. `&&` does not mean "concatenate": it means ["logical and"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators). Basically, it means "return `false` if either side of the operator is falsy, otherwise, return the right-hand-side". So this will always return `'text2=' + document.getElementById('text2').value`, because this is the right-hand-side of the `&&` operator.

You need to concatenate them, for which the operator, as you use quite correctly otherwise, is [`+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/String_Operators).

```
parameters = 'text=' + document.getElementById('text').value + '&' +  'text2=' + document.getElementById('text2').value;
```

Note that you should probably also use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to make sure you're making valid HTTP requests:

```
parameters = 'text=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('text').value) + '&' +  'text2=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('text2').value);
```

Comment: that line is even more wrong due to the missing `)` before `;`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `&&` to concatenate strings, use `+`. There are also unbalanced brackets and you are missing the "&" to separate your parameters in the URL string.

```
parameters = 'text=' + document.getElementById('text').value + '&text2=' + document.getElementById('text2').value;
```